Episode of Naruto with miniaturized characters
I stopped watching Naruto after the first 90 episodes, that was in 2005.
I came across a channel on my cable tv that showed a strange episode of Naruto.. All characters are miniaturized (cute short bodies, with large and out-of-proportion heads). 
Maybe there is a special show where all the episodes are like that..
Anyway, the episode I am looking for, is one where naruto and some other guy have both sent sakura a love letter, without knowing about each other.
They spend the rest of the time trying to locate each other's letter in sakura's purse and eventually, they find them and tear them up, realizing that they ripped both of them, too late.
At least, that is what I understood from the Arabic dubbed version, and they tend to alter the story in favor of avoiding to expose children to PG13 stuff.
